# Should I use a MBaaS platform (like Parse) or create my own backend?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, mbaas

I want to build an app that sends data from device to device (android-to-android or android-to-iOS etc.) and I was starting to look at the server side aspect.

I was thinking to myself, should I use an MBaaS platform of some kind or build the backend myself?
is it better to use MBaaS because its less time consuming?
is it better to implement it all by myself because it will require less financial resources?
any thoughts on the matter?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do look at MBaas as a starting place.  You can always decide later to 'port' your application later.  Start with your basic requirements: Authentication, Role-Based Access Control, REST API, Business Logic and Event programming.  The best part of MBaas is there dozens of vendors that will give you a free trial (like Espresso Logic).  Make sure the pricing plan meets your long-term objectives. I have built services from scratch and trying to get all the services right and integrated takes a lot longer.  Time is money - so balance the two.